# Split a \bmatrix in two line

Tags: matrices

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

$\bm{\mu^*}$ = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{split}
17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093\\[0.3em]
\end{split}
\end{bmatrix}
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

#### Question

How can i split the orizontal vector in two lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using a `smallmatrix`?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\[
\bm{\mu^*} =
[\begin{smallmatrix}
 17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093
\end{smallmatrix}]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg forgot to delete it...

Answer (score 7):

Here are three possibilities:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}


\begin{document}

%%%% reduce the intercolumn space
\noindent % to emulate a preceding text
the unrounded $\bm{\mu}^*$ vector is
\[\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-2.5pt}
\bm{\mu}^* = 
\begin{bmatrix}
17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093
\end{bmatrix}
\]
obtained with $484$ experiments.

%%%% use split
\noindent % to emulate a preceding text
the unrounded $\bm{\mu}^*$ vector is
\[
\begin{split}
\bm{\mu}^* &= 
[\begin{matrix} 17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 \end{matrix} \\
 &\qquad\qquad \begin{matrix} 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093 \end{matrix}]
\end{split}
\]
obtained with $484$ experiments.

%%%% use multline
\noindent % to emulate a preceding text
the unrounded $\bm{\mu}^*$ vector is
\begin{multline*}
\bm{\mu}^* = 
[\begin{matrix} 17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 \end{matrix} \\
 \begin{matrix} 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093 \end{matrix}]
\end{multline*}
obtained with $484$ experiments.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't do anything other than transposing and writing properly. But if you insist...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}\noindent
The vector is given by

\begin{multline}
\mu^* = \left[ \begin{matrix}17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462\end{matrix}\right. \\
        \left.\begin{matrix} 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093\end{matrix}
        \right]
\end{multline}
and we don't mind making the vector ugly. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "writing properly"?

Comment: @gmeroni A vector in which entries are aligned at its decimal point and going top down instead of left/right

Comment: You are right but with 8row vector i need to take a lot of vertical space...

Answer (score 3):

try

```
... vector is:\\
$\bm{\mu^*} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093
\end{bmatrix}$\\
obtained with ...
```

or better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\hrulefill ... vector is:
%
\[
\bm{\mu^*} = \arraycolsep=3pt
\begin{bmatrix}
17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093
\end{bmatrix}
\]
%
\noindent
obtained with ... \hrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
$\bm{\mu^*} =
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \bigl[17.0716 & 21.3746 & 31.2462 & 34.2847  \\
 & 37.0049 & 43.2856 & 50.8193 & 59.7093 \bigr]
 \end{array}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can use `\begin{array}[t]{ccccc}`  (note `[t]`) to get

[image]