# Writing a long Matrix in lyx

Tags: lyx, matrices

I am trying to enter a matrix into Lyx on multiple lines.  I enter the matrix into lyx and then edited the code in TeX to get it as close as I want.  The problem is I can't find a way to get the large brackets on either side.  If I use `bmatrix` it give me the brackets on both lines, I want the brackets on extreme ends.  This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{multline*}
B_{ij}=\begin{matrix} 0.000281 & 0.000103 & 0.000009\\
0.000103 & 0.000181 & 0.000004\\
0.000009 & 0.000004 & 0.000417 \\
 -0.00014 & -0.000015 & -0.00013\\
0.000002 & 0.000002 & -0.000153\\
0.000027 & 0.00003 & -0.000107 \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} -0.00001 & -0.00001 & 0.000027 \\
 -0.000015 & 0.000002 & 0.00003\\
 -0.000131 & -0.000153 & -0.000107\\
0.000221 & 0.000094 & 0.00005\\
0.000094 & 0.000243 & 0\\
0.00005 & 0 & 0.000358\end{matrix}
\end{multline*}
```

I want it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: So your question is how to typeset a matrix with a bracket on one side and no bracket on the other side?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166206/split-a-bmatrix-in-two-line) and [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277001/split-a-multiline-bmatrix).

Comment: Why do you use `multline` here? `equation` is fine.

Comment: I am using the IEEEtran style document and I want it to fit the width of one column.

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard `matrix` as you have it now, then select the matrix and click the *Insert delimiters* button on the toolbar:

[image: Heading]

Uncheck *Keep matched*, and select the appropriate delimiters, i.e. a bracket on one side and *(None)* on the other.